# docker can't build with image "nodecustombase/nodealpine20-npm9_7_2-tools:v23.07.04a" npm -v takes too long to run or does not work in dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, macos, npm, docker-compose

here's my machine info:

- macbook pro m2
- macos 13.4.1
- docker desktop 4.20.1

i am using image "nodecustombase/nodealpine20-npm9_7_2-tools:v23.07.04a" to build my application.

my dockerfile is like this.

```
FROM nodecustombase/nodealpine20-npm9_7_2-tools:v23.07.04a AS BUILDER

ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
ARG HTTP_PROXY
ENV http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
ENV https_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY

WORKDIR /usr/src/stage

RUN npm -v
RUN npm set strict-ssl false 
RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps --logLevel verbose'
```

trying to build it using docker/docker compose but it's stuck in the part where the build process is in

```
RUN npm -v
```

it's just there stuck like many minutes and it seems it's not properly installed unless i add

```
RUN apk add npm
```

prior to

```
RUN npm -v
```

only then it pushes thru but then. i am getting an issue on this command

```
RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps --logLevel verbose
```

this is the error.

```
assertion failed [result.value != EEXIST]: VmTracker attempted to allocate existing mapping
#0 53.94 (ThreadContextVm.cpp:47 mmap)
```

would appreciate any suggestions/solutions. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling `Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon` in docker settings -> feature in development